# Avoiding same key error in dictionary with a suffix

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, code-cleanup

I can't have the same key. But a simple (and effective) solution is put a suffix after key.

But as I'm in a foreach, I was wondering a fast and clean way to add a number suffix to duplicated keys.

e.g.:

My foreach is that:

```
foreach (Item item in items) {
    dic.Add(item.SomeKey, item.SomeValue);
}
```

But I don't want duplicated keys, so I need to 'handle' SomeKey to `Origin` become `Result`

SomeKey Origin: `key, clave, clave, chave, chave, chave`
SomeKey Result: `key, clave, clave1, chave, chave1, chave2`

---

Edit:
My answer to @KooKiz explain better the question.

I have few duplicated entries. I'm just trying to figure out how to `then increment the suffix until you find no item`. Sounds like reinvent wheels, so I was wondering if someone know a good way to do that

Comment: Can't you just add a simple incrementing integer that existing outside your loop that you call ++ on?  Like a count = 0, count++ on each key?

Comment: Do you mean you can't have duplicate keys because `Dictionary` does not permit them, or is there some requirement elsewhere that mandates non-duplicate keys? `NameValueCollection` works in much the same way as `Dictionary` but allows duplicate keys.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary if you want duplicate keys?

Comment: @DarkBobG, this will create `key, clave, clave1, chave, chave2, chave3` so this is wrong.

Comment: @WickyNilliams I must use unique keys.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I don't want duplicate keys, where you read this!?

Comment: Well, you *do* have duplicate keys and it looks like you are trying to find a way to store them in a dictionary. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Why would you need to increment the values?  The key is the only thing that's important according to your sample code, unless your sample code doesn't show us an accurate representation of what you're doing, and in that case, we CAN'T help you.

Comment: I you really want to do that, the fastest way depends on the number of duplicates.
If there's few duplicates, check if there's already an item for SomeKey, then increment the suffix until you find no item.
If there's many duplicates, create a Dictionary<TypeOfSomeKey, int> to store the indexes.

But depending on your what is your problem and what you intend to do with your dictionary, there's probably a way to avoid suffixes altogether.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I rendering a chart. If the user insert duplicated data, I'll just handle this and plot in graph. My graph framework expect a key value dic

Comment: @DarkBobG yes key is quite important, but the exactly value not. As I said to Daniel I'm rendering a chart. If the user insert duplicated data, I'll just handle this and plot in graph. My graph framework expect a key value dic.

Comment: @KooKiz Yes, this is my problem! I have few duplicated entries. I'm just trying to figure out how to `then increment the suffix until you find no item` Sounds like reinvent wheels, so I was wondering if someone know a good way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may not be the fastest, but that's the more readable I can think of:

```
        var source = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("a", "a"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("a", "b"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("b", "c"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("b", "d"),
        };

        var groups = source.GroupBy(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);

        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            int index = 0;

            foreach (var value in group)
            {
                string key = group.Key;

                if (index > 0)
                {
                    key += index;
                }

                result.Add(key, value);

                index++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var kvp in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a key with several "sub" items, Try this

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    if (myList[item.SomeKey] == null)
        myList.Add(item.SomeKey, new List<string>());
    myList[item.SomeKey].Add(item.SomeValue);
}
```

Comment: Or items.GroupBy(i => i.SomeKey, i => i.SomeValue)

Comment: no, I want to handle to my item.SomeKey list to doesn't have duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = items.GroupBy(p => p.SomeKey)
.SelectMany(q => q.Select((value, index) =>
 new Item { SomeKey = (q.Count() > 1 && index > 0) ? value.SomeKey + (index) :  
         value.SomeKey, SomeValue = value.SomeValue }))
.ToDictionary(p => p.SomeKey, q => q.SomeValue);
```